# Trying to draw an arc with context2d.arc() always results in a full circle

Tags: gwt, canvas, drawing

I'm learning how to build an web app using GWT.  I want to draw an arc but no matter the start and stop angle, I always get a full circle.  I've tried

```
context2d.arc((double)cx, (double)cy, 40., 0., 180., true);
context2d.stroke();
```

and

```
context2d.beginPath();
context2d.arc((double)cx, (double)cy, 40., 0., 180., true);
context2d.closePath();
context2d.stroke();
```

and each time I get a full circle.  I've even added `context2d.save()` before and `context2d.restore()` after and still a full circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/Context2d.html#arc%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29)

```
startAngle - the start angle, measured in radians clockwise from the positive x-axis
endAngle - the end angle, measured in radians clockwise from the positive x-axis
```

0 and 180 are in degrees.

Try instead of 180 to use 3.14159265 (which is actually 180 degress in radians)

Comment: OMG ... Radians vs. Degrees ... Now I feel really stupid.  Thanks for pointing that out  (the radians vs. degrees not that I'm stupid :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us... that is to mix radians and degrees!